# Timestamp current time is great to record the user registration, but will it change when I update the user?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a users table in my mysql database and there I record the time user signed up by having a column timeOfUserSignup (or something like that) of the type TIMESTAMP and default is set to CURRENT_TIME.

But what will happen if I update that user's info. Will that column value change to the time when the update occurred?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No, it will not be changed on updates.

A default value will only be generated if you don't pass any value on table **insertion**. If you need to change a value on updates too, then you can use an additional trigger for that.

Comment: so when I create the user and do not pass any value for the time, it will record the time of the creation there and if I update the user in the future, this value will remain unchanged? btw I can accept the answer in 8 minutes :)